# Adding multiple filters in a table

Tags: tables, filter

Is it recommended that the filter is hidden at all times displaying its elements on request or have them upfront ?

Image 1 : All filters displayed[image]

Image 2 : Add filters on request
[image]

Comment: Please take the **Tour** (Above, left, on the **Help** menu) to learn about the type of question that will get a better response. This type of question fails to pass this requirement: Don't post "Questions requesting examples of 'X'." The tour will give you ideas for modifying your question.

Comment: Hey! Welcome to UX.SE - Can you also provide a design that you've worked on? It helps us designers who're mostly visual learners to see what you've been up to and see if it's a good solution or not, thanks!

Comment: could you provide a mockup or image or your current design? I've already write an answer but I won't post it until I'm sure it applies to your question.

Comment: We're such a demanding bunch. Sorry, @Pallavi-G-Naik. Do your best with it, and you'll get more answers. :)

Comment: Hi, in the image 2, can user add the filter more than 4 filters?if user can add more than 4 filters would the design follow the image 1 style?

Answer (score 1):

Showing filters in [each column](http://demos.shieldui.com/web/grid-general/filtering) is generally more intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the nature of the business of your application this can be decided. For instance, if your are looking at a financial report sort of application you may want your filters visible at all times. Probably one wants to quickly track down a transaction in a stack by just the amount or some other meta data. Most financial applications have a lot of data displayed together, so you may need it at all times.

So, as a generic answer, I would recommend this to be decided in the amount of data you are anticipating in a single screen and/ or importance to user to drill down on detail.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I like the first version. What I like about it is the spatial mapping between the filter and the data. This can further be improved by moving the filter in the table header.

Always remember to show a strong signifier when the data is filtered to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

If your audience has not an IT way of thinkink, I will advice you to choose 3-4 **useful** filters for your users.

For example `Name` and `Location` should be cover by the search field, and maybe some roles (if it is really useful) filter or business filter (like new users since last visit)(In my mind the email adress is not a field we use a lot for research)